# onActivityResult crashes when custom location for video (MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, URI) is set

Tags: output, onactivityresult, mediastore, extra

So this is my setup for the 'intent':

```
Intent cameraACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

tempUri = accessLocalStorage.getThisAppsStorageUriPath();

//Crashed for tempUri = "/data/user/0/hardy.android.go/app_files/test.mp4"
//Crashed for tempUri = "/data/user/0/hardy.android.go/app_files/"
cameraACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempUri);

cameraACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE.setFlags(cameraACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

startActivityForResult(cameraACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE, 
Integer.parseInt( DataModel.SETVIDEORECORDING.toString()));
```

Video intent starts as expected and crashes once I finish recording - it doesn't even make it to 'onActivityResult'. Error is:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

Don't know why there is a Bitmap floating around in there?

Anywayz, so in an attempt to try and pinpoint the issue, I comment out the following and go again:

```
cameraACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempUri);
```

and it works :( - video is stored here:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20181004_213440310_HDR.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a partial answer. In terms of the application not crashing, I made progress by using [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) to generate the Uri.

```
tempUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
context,
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
new File(accessLocalStorage.getThisAppsStorageUriPath().getPath())
);
```

However, the video File saved at the path in the Uri was of size/length 0 () and I didn't have time to work through this and so, this story ends here :( - hope this is of some help for others!